# Saving data to server from aui datatable TextAreaCellEditor

Tags: yui, alloy-ui, liferay-aui

How can we save data from AUI DataTable Text Area Cell Editor to server.
I am doing something like:

```
var nameEditor = new Y.TextAreaCellEditor({
validator : {
   rules: {
    name:{
      email:true,
      required:true,
}
}
}
});
```

How can I get a handler to send a request to server in order to save data from that editor column

Answer (score 2):

The [base editor](https://github.com/liferay/alloy-ui/blob/master/src/aui-datatable/js/aui-datatable-base-cell-editor.js) registers a `save` event to which you would want to listen.

To register the subscription:

```
nameEditor.on('save', function(e){
      var msg = 'Details : newVal=' + e.newVal
                       + ' oldVal=' + e.prevVal;
      alert(msg)
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/vbeXL/)

Comment: Could you call this from a `TextAreaCellEditor` that is defined in a column and not as a variable i.e., `{ key: 'id',label: 'ID', sortable: true,  editor: new Y.TextAreaCellEditor()},`

Comment: @ClayBanks you can define the listener in the construction parameters. Have a look a [modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/vbeXL/1/)